# How to use scanner input in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want user to key in some input, the setter method is on the other class, but I don't know how to write the code. Did I miss something or make some mistake?

Here is my code.

Project.java

```
public class Project
{

private String projectName;

//constructor 
public Project()
{
    projectName = "No Project";
}

//projectName setter
public void setProjectName(String projectName)
{
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

//projectName getter
public String getProjectName()
{
    return projectName;
}

//display info
public void displayInfo ()
{   
    System.out.println("**PROJECT DETAILS**");
    System.out.println("Project Name : " + projectName);
}
} //close class
```

DisplayProject.java

```
public class DisplayProject
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //create object
    Project createProject = new Project();

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //enter project name
    System.out.print("Enter project name: ");
    createProject.setProjectName(projectName) = input.nextLine(); <Here is my problem>

} // close main class
} //close class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it

```
createProject.setProjectName(input.nextLine());
```

instead of

```
createProject.setProjectName(projectName) = input.nextLine();
```

---

You can do in this way as well that makes more sense

```
String projectName = input.nextLine();  // read a line
createProject.setProjectName(projectName);
```

Comment: @SyasyaAzizan Do not forget to tick this answer as correct answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
createProject.setProjectName(input.nextLine());
```

What you have done is incorrect syntax. It will not even compile.